# How do I join 2 tables in ServiceStack OrmLite and select both classes?

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I'd like to do a simple SQL join in ServiceStack OrmLite and get both tables as the corresponding .NET objects.

In LINQ-to-Entities it would be something like this:

```
Claim.Join(Policy, c => c.PolicyId, p => p.Id, (c, p) => new { Claim = c, Policy = p })
```

This would give me an anonymous type with `Claim` and `Policy` properties.

I've looked at the OrmLite [Advanced Join Example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#advanced-example), but that only selects some of the properties of each type into a 3rd type of object (`FullCustomerInfo`). I don't want to repeat all my properties in another object, I just want to use the existing objects.

In reality, the query can be much more complex, e.g.

```
Claim.Join(Policy, c => c.PolicyId, p => p.Id, (c, p) => new { Claim = c, Policy = p })
    .Where(o => o.Policy.Something > o.Claim.Something)
    .Select(o => o.Claim.SomethingElse)
```

... etc., but even if OrmLite could just do the join in SQL and I had to do the rest in memory it would be a good start.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This wasn't available in OrmLite previously but as it's a nice feature to have I've just added support for `SelectMulti<T,T2,..>` and `SelectMultiAsync` [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/b8b26326ce46ac04191eedba4589d59fd4afaafd) which now lets you read up to 7 of your joined tables from a single query.

So to use OrmLite's Advanced Join Example you can construct a typed Join Query with:

```
var q = db.From<Customer>()
    .Join<Customer, CustomerAddress>()
    .Join<Customer, Order>();
```

Then use the `SelectMulti` APIs to populate the tables you're interested in, e.g:

```
var results = db.SelectMulti<Customer, CustomerAddress, Order>(q);
```

Which will return a `List<Tuple<T,T2,T3>>` giving you typed access to your populated POCOs from tables in your joined query.

If preferred, there's also an async version:

```
var results = await db.SelectMultiAsync<Customer, CustomerAddress, Order>(q);
```

The new `SelectMulti` APIs are available from v4.0.57 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

### Create Typed Queries in OrmLite and Execute them in Dapper

An alternative is to use a combination of OrmLite to create the typed query using its built-in [Reference Conventions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-conventions) and then use OrmLite's embedded version of Dapper to Query Multiple result-sets into your existing POCO Types.

To start with create your Typed Query Expression and have it return all fields from all tables with:

```
var q = db.From<Customer>()
    .Join<Customer, CustomerAddress>()
    .Join<Customer, Order>()
    .Select("*");
```

Then pass the generated SQL from the above typed SQL Expression into Dapper's Query Multiple feature to read the results into a List of Tuples of the different joined tables:

```
using (var multi = db.QueryMultiple(q.ToSelectStatement()))
{
    var results = multi.Read<Customer, CustomerAddress, Order, 
        Tuple<Customer,CustomerAddress,Order>>(Tuple.Create).ToList();

    foreach (var tuple in results)
    {
        "Customer:".Print();
        tuple.Item1.PrintDump();

        "Customer Address:".Print();
        tuple.Item2.PrintDump();

        "Order:".Print();
        tuple.Item3.PrintDump();
    }
}
```

Which prints out something like:

```
Customer:
{
    Id: 1,
    Name: Customer 1
}
Customer Address:
{
    Id: 1,
    CustomerId: 1,
    AddressLine1: 1 Australia Street,
}
Order:
{
    Id: 1,
    CustomerId: 1,
    LineItem: Line 1,
    Qty: 1,
    Cost: 1.99
}    
Customer:
{
    Id: 1,
    Name: Customer 1
}
Customer Address:
{
    Id: 1,
    CustomerId: 1,
    AddressLine1: 1 Australia Street,
}
Order:
{
    Id: 2,
    CustomerId: 1,
    LineItem: Line 2,
    Qty: 2,
    Cost: 2.99
}
```

Comment: "No, there was no way, but yes, there is now" - now that's an answer! :D Thanks very much.

Comment: Now, if we could just continue to add to the SQL query after the join, using both tables, e.g. something like `db.From<Customer>().Join<Customer, CustomerAddress>().Where(t => t.Item1.Name.Length > t.Item2.City.Length).Select(t => new[] { t.Item1.Name, t.Item2.City });` (silly example, but you get the idea)

Comment: You can add an expression in the Join() and use Where<T1,T2>((t1,t2) => ...) later

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to add an expression to Join() to control what it returns. The Func<> it takes returns bool, so I presume that's just "JOIN ON ..." expression. Could you give an example?

Comment: No you can't change what it returns, it's just a JOIN condition that maps to a normal SQL INNER JOIN condition

Comment: Then how do I use the `Where<T1,T2>` ? .Where() seem to have only one type parameter and it's the same one as in the original From ("Customer" in this example).

Comment: @EM See this [SqlExpression for a Where example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/cf17ebc03d574d517a49fe3e4727ec877c88c950/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/Expression/ComplexJoinTests.cs#L185)

Comment: thanks, that works! (Even though I don't see Where<T1, T2> in IntelliSense somehow...) What about selecting some of the columns (from both tables) in the SQL - is that possible? I adding `.Select(new string[] { "Name", "City"})` after the .Join(), but that seems to have no effect - I still get back the original two classes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the only way to select which fields are returned is with `.Select()` APIs. But yeah you can use Select to [return an anonymous type from multiple tables](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/cf17ebc03d574d517a49fe3e4727ec877c88c950/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/Expression/ComplexJoinTests.cs#L263) , you can also [select an array of columns from multiple tables](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/AutoQueryTests.cs#L259).

Comment: I mean, in the `Does_only_populate_Select_fields_wildcard example`, how would I get `Department2.Name` ? `results` is a list of `DeptEmployee` objects, so it doesn't contain any properties of `Department2`.

Comment: It's better if you open a new question as comments isn't the right place for code, but you can fetch it with: `db.Column<string>(db.From<DeptEmployee>().Join<Department2>().Select(new[] { "Name" }))` or `db.Column<string>(db.From<DeptEmployee>().Join<Department2>().Select<DeptEmployee,Department2>((e,d) => new { d.Name }))` you can also [fetch dynamic results](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#dynamic-result-sets) by selecting a `List<object>` or `Dictionary<string,object>` Types.

Comment: Yes, good point, I've posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442401/ormlite-query-to-select-some-of-the-columns-from-each-of-2-joined-tables

`.Column()` is not enough, because I want to select some columns from each of the joined tables.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do a Distinct on a SelectMulti, at the SQL level, not after the query execution?

Comment: Anytime I read anything with static methods on primitive .NET types, I know who's content I am reading.

:)